# How to convert all column of dataframe to numeric spark scala?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I loaded a csv as dataframe. I would like to cast all columns to float, knowing that the file is to big to write all columns names:

```
val spark = SparkSession.builder.master("local").appName("my-spark-app").getOrCreate()
val df = spark.read.option("header",true).option("inferSchema", "true").csv("C:/Users/mhattabi/Desktop/dataTest2.csv")
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Given this DataFrame as example:

```
val df = sqlContext.createDataFrame(Seq(("0", 0),("1", 1),("2", 0))).toDF("id", "c0")
```

with schema:

```
StructType(
    StructField(id,StringType,true), 
    StructField(c0,IntegerType,false))
```

You can loop over DF columns by **.columns** functions:

```
val castedDF = df.columns.foldLeft(df)((current, c) => current.withColumn(c, col(c).cast("float")))
```

So the new DF schema looks like:

```
StructType(
    StructField(id,FloatType,true), 
    StructField(c0,FloatType,false))
```

**EDIT:**

If you wanna exclude some columns from casting, you could do something like (supposing we want to exclude the column **id**):

```
val exclude = Array("id")

val someCastedDF = (df.columns.toBuffer --= exclude).foldLeft(df)((current, c) =>
                                              current.withColumn(c, col(c).cast("float")))
```

where `exclude` is an Array of all columns we want to exclude from casting.

So the schema of this new DF is:

```
StructType(
    StructField(id,StringType,true), 
    StructField(c0,FloatType,false))
```

Please notice that maybe this is not the best solution to do it but it can be a starting point.

Comment: You can use `foldLeft` on the `columns` to refrain from using a mutable `var`: `df.columns.foldLeft(df)((current, c) => current.withColumn(c, col(c).cast("float")))`

Comment: one last question before i accept your answer ,if i would like to exclude a specefic column that i would like to cast to timestamp type for exemple ,,while looping on the other columns .Thanks to update the solution

Comment: @user7394882 Do you already know the names of the columns you want to exclude from casting?

Comment: @pheeleeppoo yesi know the name of the column i need to exclude what should i do please thank